# Are projects created using Qt WASM required to be under GPL?

Tags: gpl

As I understand, the core modules of Qt are under LGPL and can be used in a closed source project.
But the Qt WASM module is under GPL. I'm not sure if it's linked into the project or only acts as a build system.

If I create a wasm project using Qt (and by extension, the Qt WASM module), will it fall under GPL or can it be closed source?

And if it falls under GPL, is it considered 'distribution' if hosted on a server and accessed by a browser?

Comment: "I'm not sure if it's linked into the project or only acts as a build system" - as you've surmised, it is necessary to know this in order to answer your question. If you're linking in GPL code to a product, and then you distribute that product, then yes, you'd have to make your own product code GPL as well.

Comment: From what I read Qt WASM is not just a compiler, but both, compiler and standard library for that compiler. That means that parts of it will end in the resulting binary which means the resulting binary must follow its license, thus GPL or paid-for proprietary. (And that is likely the reason for the choice of GPL there over LGPL).